# Which is correct? Class starting soon or class is starting soon

Tags: grammar

" The class starting soon" or "the class is starting soon"
Hello, may I know which sentences as shown above is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. This is a question more suited to our site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). I would suggest asking there, or seeing if they have an answer already.

Answer (score 3):

The correct usage would be 'the class is starting soon.' 'The class' is the subject, and it is starting soon.

Answer (score -3):

When something is going to start, like a class, it starts only once and after that the thing that is continuous is the class not start. Actually start is not a real verb cause it doesn't do anything. I think it is better to say class will start soon. I am not a grammar teacher I just thing it is not right to add ing to start. please let me know what you think about this.

Comment: What we think about this is that it is wrong.